# Codeigniter: Create a dynamic ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to ask on how can I create a dynamic ID in the fields that I have loaded.

Here is my view:

```
        <div id="content">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="location.reload();"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?php // echo $tablename; ?></legend>
            <table id="table_main">
                <tr>
                    <th>Column Name:</th>
                    <th>Type:</th>
                    <th>Length/Values:</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($updatemaintenance1 as $field) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $field->name; ?>" style="width: 80%"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <select style="width: 80%">
                            <option><?php echo $field->type; ?></option>
                            <option>INT</option>
                            <option>VARCHAR</option>
                            <option>TEXT</option>
                            <option>DATE</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $field->max_length; ?>" style="width: 100%"/></td>

                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php //foreach ($tablename as $row1) { ?>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ninja79" name="ninja79" value="<?php echo $table_name1; ?>"/></td>
                    <?php// } ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn_editinventorytype btn-info btn-sm">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn_deleteinventorytype btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a foreach loop where I placed all the values from my database. What I want is to generate an ID on the textboxes and the selectbox. And I have this code in the model where I can modify the loaded fields.

Here is my model:

```
public function modify_table($modify){
     $fields = array($modify[''] = array('name' => $modify[''],
                                         'type' => $modify[''],
                                         'constraint' => $modify['']),

         );
         $this->dbforge->modify_column($modify['ninja79'], $fields);
 }
```

This codes are not as simple as `'SELECT * FROM 'tablename'` I mean I'm talking about modifying tables in the database, so please could you help me? All I want is to have a dynamic ID in my model and in my view. I have no idea on how to code that. This is confusing so PLEASE I need your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: its unclear what you want to happen, but if you want a dynamic id for your element a `uniqid` or `mt_random` would suffice for short loops. but why what would you need the `ID` for when you have the `input name` are you submitting your form through ajax?

Comment: or send your input via an `array`? `name="ninja79[]"` so that all will be group inside an array?

Comment: @TomeӾsanS: It's like i want my system to be a database itself. Do you want a print screen of this view? I can edit my question..

Comment: hmm still cant understand, are you making something like `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @TomeӾsanS: Yep something like that, I am trying to make a maintenance of my system where in the user can modify the tables on the database, all in all, the user can also access the database through this system, the user can modify, add and delete a table in the database.

Comment: so its not a database by itslef but a `DBMS`. any way you can create dynamic id easily by `<input id="<?=uniqid();?>">` its up to you to increase the entropy

Comment: @TomeӾsanS: I have another question if you don't mind, how can I get the value of that unique ID in the model?

Comment: you cannot, unless you add it in your form to be submitted. I can't see why you are doing this are you using the id to group the form input values? i told you earlier use an array to group all the input together.\ `<input name="test[]">`

Comment: @TomeӾsanS: I've used that, sorry I mean how can i get the value of the textbox with a unique name not a unique ID to place it in the code in my model.